# Angular 2 : Multiple included error

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, ionic2

I try to build an Ionic 2 app based on Angular 2 framework.
I have to display a map in a page. I use this : 
https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/

It works good, but I have this error in my console :

```
You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
```

In fact, I use the geometry google library in a component to calcul some time travel. So I have Include this in my index.html :

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&key=MYAPIKEY&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

If I remove that, I haven't my error I my map page, but I can't use the library to calcul distance in my provider ...

**Someone can explain how I can use the two functionalities ?**

My provider code to calcul distance :

```
//this line doesn't works if I remove my script from my index.html 
 let origin = new google.maps.LatLng(user.latitude, user.longitude);   
    let service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix(
            {
                origins: [origin],
                destinations: destinations,
                travelMode: 'DRIVING',
            }, res =>{
                if(res.rows[0]) {
                    for(let i: number = 0; i < res.rows[0].elements.length ; i++) {
                        let element: any = res.rows[0].elements[i];
                        objects[i].distance = element.distance.text;
                        objects[i].time_travel = element.duration.text;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since google maps api script is being added by '@agm/core' while calling the map directive, it is redundant to add maps api reference in the index file. This was the reason for above error.

So please make the following changes

in your components class import MapsAPILoader

```
import { AgmCoreModule, MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
```

Add the below code in the app component constructor

```
 constructor(private _loader:MapsAPILoader)
{
  _loader.load().then(() => {
  console.log('google script loaded');
});

}
```

Finally remove the map script from index file.

Comment: Done. But I keep an error when my geometry function is called : Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: google is not defined
ReferenceError: google is not defined

Comment: @V.Pivet updated the answer. Please check and let me know.

Comment: I done your modification and I have one time the log in my console. I don't my error anymore.

Answer (score 1):

AGM offers a way to load your map on your own using the MapsAPILoader

```
    import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';
    ...
    this.mapsLoader.load().then(() => {
       console.log('maps loaded');
    });
```